# Is it possible to display one faceted chart in Altair at a time and toggle between different charts?

Tags: altair

I'm working on a project for a class where I've been creating faceted scatterplots in Altair where each chart is a different type of food. I was wondering if it would be possible to still use these faceted charts but only display one at a time and give the user the ability to toggle between graphs instead of having each graph displayed one after the other?
[Here is a rough diagram of what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVH2u.png) and here's the code I have now (and [what the output looks like at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWg2e.png)):

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

hover = alt.selection_single(on='mouseover', nearest=True, empty='none')

base = alt.Chart("Food Nutrition Info Compiled.csv").encode(
    x='Energ_Kcal:N',
    y='Water_(g):Q',
    color=alt.condition(hover, 'Type:N', alt.value('lightgray'))
).properties(
    width=180,
    height=180,
)

points = base.mark_point().add_selection(
    hover
)

text = base.mark_text(dy=-5).encode(
    text = 'Shrt_Desc:N',
    opacity = alt.condition(hover, alt.value(1), alt.value(0))
)

alt.layer(points, text).facet(
    'Type:N',
)
```

Thanks and I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displaying one faceted chart at a time sounds the same as showing a single subset of the data at any one point. This is currently possible by creating a selection that is bound to e.g. a dropdown and the using that with `transform_filter`:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data


source = data.cars()

dropdown_options = source['Origin'].unique().tolist()

dropdown = alt.binding_select(
    options=dropdown_options,
    name='Origin '
)
selection = alt.selection_multi(
    fields=['Origin'],
    value=[{'Origin': dropdown_options[0]}],
    bind=dropdown
)

alt.Chart(source).mark_circle().encode(
    x=alt.X('Weight_in_lbs:Q', title=''),
    y='Horsepower',
    color='Origin',
).add_selection(
    selection
).transform_filter(
    selection
)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how this would be adapted for a dataset where the type must be specified (i.e. 'Type: N')? When I ran it and implemented my own data source, I got the error message "string indices must be integers" on the dropdown_options line. Thank you though, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: @LeoStrong You can only use `source['Origin'].unique().tolist()` if you have read the data into a pandas dataframe first. If you want to use a URL as the data source in Altair, you need to manually type out the list of options that you want in the dropdown instead of computing it from the unique values in the dataframe column (which is what that line does)